# VIM - Change Inside ? or Select Inside?

Tags: vim

In vim, I'm trying to change inside parantheses or brackets without luck

I'm using `ci(` and `ci[` but no luck

```
write (*, '(a)')
```

If I try to change everything inside the `(` `)`, `ci(` does not work, but if I do `ci'` it actually lets me change everything inside `'`

Comment: It **must** work --- run `vim --clean` to check this. Then revise your vimrc to find what mappings/plugins cause such weird behaviour.

Comment: `ci(` only works if your cursor is already somwhere inside the parentheses. Not like `ci'` where you can be at the begninning of the line.

Comment: @perelo you are right. Then how can I from the beginning of the line, delete inside the () and go into insert mode?

Answer (score 1):

With vanilla vim, the `i'` and `a'` text objects allow you to select the *next* text surrounded by `'` even if your cursor is way before the targetted `'`. Although, `i(`, `a(`, `i[`, `a[`, ... requires that your cursor is already inside the target parentheses. Thus to select the next text inside `(`, you must first go to the first `(` character with `f(`, then `ci(`.

Otherwise, there is [targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim) that adds alot of new text objects and modifies `i(`-like behaviours to make it more like `i'`.